# Is there a quick and easy way to replace all Unicode characters with their HTML equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, html, unicode

Right now I use this page to do this:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp

```
$info = str_replace("©", "&copy;", $info);
$info = str_replace("®", "&reg;", $info);
$info = str_replace("•", "&bull;", $info);
$info = str_replace("½", "&frac12;", $info);
$info = str_replace("é", "&eacute;", $info);
$info = str_replace("€", "&euro;", $info);
```

Is there a quick way (like a single PHP function) that can do ALL of the HTML conversions for me?

Comment: Have you tried the builtin [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a built in function, htmlentities. In your case, you would want to do this:

```
$info = htmlentities($info);
```